# Drawing switching circuit switches

Tags: circuitikz

I want to draw the following pictures.
[image][image]

I am new to `circuitikz`. It would be so much helpful for me to know the step-by-step procedure about making coordinates, drawing the black dots, that broken part of the lines for closed switch etc.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4size][article]
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
        (0,0)   to   [short,-*]     (1,0)    coordinate 
        to [nos,l=$x$,-*]  ++ (3,0) 
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\caption{Open switch}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But this is not convincing for me and I also don't know what `[short,-*],[nos,l=$x$,-*]` these are for.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See documentation for `circuitikz` package. There are example of different switches, among them seems that can help you `quote switches`.

Comment: @Zarko i went through the documentation. but I did not find how to draw `/` type line in that image

Comment: *3.23 Switches and buttons*, page 110

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in the comments